# How to make and pass an object with multiple keys into a php curl http post

Tags: php, node.js, curl

As a premise, I have written a bunch of endpoints for one of my company's portals using nodejs. Now I have to make the same functionality in another one of our portals but this portal was built in php... And I am VERY new to php.

What I have works, but it just seems sloppy and I end up having to do some string manipulation in the endpoint to get out what I need. Also, I'm pretty sure I'm not using curl the way I'm supposed to. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have

```
$params = array('userID' => $userID, 'UnitID' => $unitid);
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $params .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
}

$url = 'https://10.4.2.31:4000/api/TestCurl/' . $params;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

And an example of the result I'm getting in node is

{params: 'ArrayuserID=12345678&UnitID=ABC1234&'}

My test endpoint in looks like this

```
app.post('/api/TestCurl/:params', UserCtrl.TestCurl);
```

Comment: Hint: `json_encode` works great for encoding trees of data.

Comment: your curl says your posting, but the parameters are in the url? so which do you want?

Comment: @rtfm Whichever way is the cleanest is preferred. Which way would you do it?

Comment: POST for posting data, is the 'standard'; but im not clear if your retrieving from the API then you should be using GET

Comment: I'll be posting using the parameters  "$params". For now, I'm just testing out curl to see if I can properly pass the data I need to node. So when I hit the real endpoints, I know it will work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `http_build_query()` to convert an array into a format for use with curl.

For a POST request:

```
$params = array('userID' => $userID, 'UnitID' => $unitid);
$fields_string = http_build_query($params);
// ...
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```

The reason for the output you give is that you are defining `$params` as an array, but then concatenating it as a string inside the `foreach` loop. Your approach would work if you used a different variable name inside the loop.

Comment: I tried that and it still wont pass the userID and UnitID to node. The only way I've been able to do that is by passing the parameters through the url. But it just feels sloppy to me. I dont know if node somehow doesnt see it, or if my curl code is wrong. :/

Comment: I also tried changing name of the variable in the loop and still get "{params: 'ArrayuserID=12345678&UnitID=ABC1234&'}" as my req.params value.

Comment: I see what you were saying now. When using a different variable, it gets rid of "Array" and the beginning of my req.params.  Its still not my ideal way of doing it, but that solves the "Array" part of it haha. Thanks!